# Insert Formula into Cell where Part of the Formula Depends on Value in Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I know this is probably super simple, but I've never done it before in VBA and can't find an existing question that's on-point.

I'm looping through a group of worksheets, generating new ones, and inserting content based on conditions/values in a source sheet ("X-Availability").  One of those values is a number that I want to be part of a formula that gets inserted into a column of cells.  On the first iteration, that is at H2 from ("X-Availability").  On the next iteration, H3, etc.

If I was manually typing this formula into Excel, I would have typed `=INT($N2/('X-Availability'!$H$2+0.1))+1` and filled down.  Then on the next sheet I'd just change the `$H$2` to `$H$3`.  Since I'm in a VBA loop, I obviously need to do something differently.

Here is what I have so far that isn't working.  (application-defined or object-defined error) What am I missing here?

Please assume that the FOR loop and the WITH end properly already.

```
    With ThisWorkbook
    Set r = .Sheets("X-Availability").Range("B2:B" & lastrow(Worksheets("X-Availability")))

        For Each c In r
            .Sheets(c.Offset(0, 3).Value).Copy after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            With ActiveSheet
                .Name = c
                lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("K2:K" & lrow).Value = c.Offset(0, -1)
                .Range("L2:L" & lrow).Value = c
                .Range("M2:M" & lrow).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)
                .Range("N2:N" & lrow).Value = ("=ROW($N2)-1")
 -------------> .Range("O2:O" & lrow).Formula = "=INT($N2/(" & c.Offset(0, 6) & "+.1))+1"
                .Range("P2:P" & lrow).Value = ("=COUNTIF($O:$O,$O2)")
                .Range("Q2:Q" & lrow).Value = ("=IF($P2<100,$O2-1,$O2)")
                .Range("R2:R" & lrow).Value = ("=CONCATENATE(K2,"" "",Q2)")
                .Range("S2:S" & lrow).Value = ("=CONCATENATE(""CA_Full_"",RC[-7],"" "",RC[-2],""_"",'X-User Input'!R4C2)")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need the formula to reference the cell location and not the value.  Try using `.address` like this: `c.Offset(0, 6).Address`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my dad always says, if you find yourself banging your head against the wall long enough, something good might slip in while the blood slips out.

I just started trying random things all with varying errors.  I ultimately just dimmed a string for the value inside the problem cell and added the "+ 0.1" at that point.  Then called the string on the formula line.  Since I put it within the loop, it changes to the correct cell value on each subsequent iteration.  Worked fine.

There was an extra ) as well.  Hope this helps anyone else who might run across it in the future!

```
                With ActiveSheet
                .Name = c
                Divisor = c.Offset(0, 6) + 0.1
                lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("K2:K" & lrow).Value = c.Offset(0, -1)
                .Range("L2:L" & lrow).Value = c
                .Range("M2:M" & lrow).Value = c.Offset(0, 1)
                .Range("N2:N" & lrow).Value = ("=ROW($N2)-1")
                .Range("O2:O" & lrow).Formula = "=INT($N2/" & Divisor & ")+1"
                .Range("P2:P" & lrow).Value = ("=COUNTIF($O:$O,$O2)")
                .Range("Q2:Q" & lrow).Value = ("=IF($P2<100,$O2-1,$O2)")
                .Range("R2:R" & lrow).Value = ("=CONCATENATE(K2,"" "",Q2)")
                .Range("S2:S" & lrow).Value = ("=CONCATENATE(""CA_Full_"",RC[-7],"" "",RC[-2],""_"",'X-User Input'!R4C2)")
```